# change data using checkbox

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I want to change data in a sql table by using checkbox.  I have successfully echo all the data of my table. but, I can not delete.  after I enter the new data et click on checkbox and submit. the data go back to the orignial data.   can anyone help me please?  thank you so much.

```
<?php


include_once("mesparametres.inc.php");  
$sql="SELECT * FROM poisson";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="modifier.php">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">


<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Nom</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Classe</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>eau</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>nourriture</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>couleur</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>taille</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>vie</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>dateacqui</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>modifier</strong></td>

</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="id<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" /><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="nom<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="nom" value="<? echo $rows['nom']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="classe<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="classe" value="<? echo $rows['classe']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="eau<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="eau" value="<? echo $rows['eau']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="nourriture<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="nourriture" value="<? echo $rows['nourriture']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="couleur<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="couleur" value="<? echo $rows['couleur']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="taille<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="taille" value="<? echo $rows['taille']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="vie<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="vie" value="<? echo $rows['vie']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="dateacqui<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" type="text" id="dateacqui" value="<? echo $rows['dateacqui']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="modifier[]>" type="checkbox" id="modifier[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" ></td>
</tr>
<?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];}?>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php
// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if($Submit)
{
foreach($_POST['id'] as $id)
{


$sql1="UPDATE poisson SET nom='".$_POST["nom".$id]."', classe='".$_POST["classe".$id]."', eau='".$_POST["eau".$id]."',nourriture='".$_POST["nourriture".$id]."',couleur='".$_POST["couleur".$id]."',taille='".$_POST["taille".$id]."',vie='".$_POST["vie".$id]."',dateacqui='".$_POST["dateacqui".$id]."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}


mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest to store that POST-data in variables for clarity :)
Then try run the query without storing it, i.e:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET nom='variable1', classe='variable2' WHERE id='condition';
```

and so on, just like you did. You need also the attribute 'checked' i.e. `checked="yes"`

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are checked or not based on the `checked` [HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp), not the `value` attribute:

This:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Not this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

The value is what gets submitted along with the form when, for example, you group a bunch of checkboxes by using the same `name` attribute.